# jquery on localhost

Tags: apache, apache2, linux-mint

I am using Linuxmint (= ubuntu linux 9.10)
I installed LAmp server which have apache,php mysql
and now i am trying to write jquery code
i made a file and it worked perfectly with this link :  file:///var/www/jquery/jquery.html
but when i use this link, then it doesnt work anymore : http://localhost/jquery/jquery.html

the file jquery.min.js is in the same folder
and i already changed the src of it in source code to

1. `<script type="text/javascript" src="/var/www/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>`
2. `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>`

but none of them works (with localhost link)
using firebug I saw these errors:

1. The requested URL /var/www/jquery/jquery.min.js was not found on this server.
2. You don't have permission to access /jquery/jquery.min.js
   on this server.

Apache/2.2.12 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

so what do I have to do to make it run?

Comment: This should go into severfault, I think. It relates to apache configuration, instead of jquery.

Comment: this looks like a file permissions issue try something like `cd /var/www/; sudo chmod 600 ./*`. Long live Linux Mint (I'm on LMDE).

Answer (score 2):

The second approach should work, if the apache server has read access to file `/var/www/jquery/jquery.min.js`.

Answer (score 1):

If apache's user is wwwrun and the group is www, do the following:

```
chmod -R 0744 /var/www/
chown -R wwwrun:www /var/www/
```

This will ensure, that the apache user will have the rights to view, execute, etc. the files in your web-folder.

Comment: On most *nix systems, commands can be case sensitive. It's not `Chmod`, it's `chmod`.

Comment: Thanks, must've hit the shift, like writing a new sentence and overseen it.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to make sure your Apache configuration allows you to serve js files.

Try to access http://localhost/jquery/jquery.min.js and see if you can get the file.